# Ipython notebook: Bearcart import

Tags: ipython

I am trying to plot some data using pandas and the bearcart package in Ipython Notebook, and while it gives me the object, it doesn't actually plot the graph itself. So it looks like this:

```
vis = bearcart.Chart(df)
bearcart.bearcart.Chart at 0x107b28a50
```

I also tried using the command bearcart.initialize_notebook() but it gives me this error:

```
bearcart.initialize_notebook()
'module' object has no attribute 'initialize_notebook'
```

Thanks